# Extending an instance with methods from another instance of another class

Tags: ruby, inheritance, instance

Currently I am doing something like the following to have the `Runnable` classes' `run` method access methods of the `ExecutionContext`:

```
class ExecutionContext
  def message(text)
    puts "ExecutionContext.message: #{text}"
  end 
  def answer?
    puts "ExecutionContext.answer called"
    true
  end
end

class Controller
  def do_run(context)
    @context = context
    run
    @context = nil
  end

  def method_missing(mth, *args)
    @context.send(mth, *args)
  end
end

class Runnable < Controller
  def run
    if answer?
      message "Runnable's block executing!"
    end
  end
end

runnable = Runnable.new

context = ExecutionContext.new
runnable.do_run(context)
```

The idea is that the `Runnable` class is written by "end users" who want to access functionality (such as the `message` and `answer?` methods) of an `ExecutionContext` instance which is provided from elsewhere. In fact, the `Runnable` class is all the "end user" is concerned about and it should be as small and simple as possible.

The code above works as expected in that all methods called by `Runnable.run` are provided by the `ExecutionContext`.

However I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same thing, where I can avoid using `method_missing` and defining the temporary `@context` instance variable.

Ideally, I would like to modify the code to something similar to this (`ExecutionContext` stays the same):

```
class Controller
  def do_run(context, runnable)
    runnable.extend_from_instance(context)
    runnable.run
  end
end

class Runnable
  def run
    if answer?
      message "Runnable's block executing!"
    end
  end
end

runnable = Runnable.new
context = ExecutionContext.new
Controller.new.do_run(context, runnable)
```

Is there such thing as `extend_from_instance`?

### Update

Thanks everyone for looking into this.

Since it has come up in the two answers I got so far, I realised I should mention the following restrictions: Unfortunately neither `Runnable` nor `ExecutionContext` can be turned into `module`s. They need to be `class`es as their instances will behave differently for different cases (both will have their own instance variables etc).

I really need the `run` method to execute as if it was part of the `ExecutionContext` *instance* (`context` in the code).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't want to use `method_missing` in this case.

I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps `define_block` is not the correct name...?

However, a module seems to have the functionality that you want.

```
module Messaging
  def message(text)
    puts "Provider.message: #{text}"
  end 
end

class Parent
  include Messaging
  ...
```

EDIT: I think you want to use binding. It allows you to pass the current scope (context) to another scope.

```
def print_local binding
  puts 'local is ' + binding.eval('local')
end

def foo
  local = 'value'
  print_local binding
end

foo 
=> local is value
```

In this case, print_local wants to print foo's `local` variable. But it doesn't have access to it because `local` exists only in foo's scope (or context).

So, you can pass in foo's scope as `binding`.

See [binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand, this will not execute the `define_block` code in the context of the `Provider` (in your case `Messaging`), but in the context of the `Parent`. I know my names are strange, I was trying to explain that `define_block` only holds the code (which could be a block instead of a method but I'm not sure) to be executed in the `Provider`'s context.

Comment: Now I really don't understand. I think your concept of "context" may need clarification. The context is set by the object that is calling the method. So, when you call `child.run_block` it is run in the child's context. Perhaps you can rework your example to express your question better....

Comment: I reworked the question, hope it is more clear now - let me know, thanks!

Comment: +1 for mentioning `binding`, I wasn't aware of this powerful feature! Unfortunately when trying to [incorporate it into my desired code](http://bit.ly/1ITAxiI), I noticed that whatever gets executed by `eval` inherits the execution context of that binding *only*, there is nothing left of the original context (such as the `runnable` instance or its `run` method). Or, [with a slightly different configuration](http://bit.ly/1P4ZCfN) the `ExecutionContext`'s instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think what [B Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30090140/2140872) said was correct. It makes the most sense to create the shared functionality in a `Module` and `include` that module in the class. However if you *really* want something like your `extend_from_instance` you can use Ruby's [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-extend) method to dynamically extend the module in an instance of the class (though I think this is a bad idea). Working form your desired code:

```
module ExecutionContext
  def message(text)
    puts "ExecutionContext.message: #{text}"
  end 
  def answer?
    puts "ExecutionContext.answer called"
    true
  end
end

class Controller
  def do_run(context_module, runnable)
    runnable.extend(context_module)
    runnable.run
  end
end

class Runnable
  def run
    if answer?
      message "Runnable's block executing!"
    end
  end
end

runnable = Runnable.new
Controller.new.do_run(ExecutionContext, runnable)
```

Again though, this is a bad idea and will probably come back to bite you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two things: 1. Unfortunately I need `ExecutionContext` to be a class as it has to behave differently for different instances. 2. Could you give an example/explanation why extending like that is a bad idea and how it might bite?

Comment: For one, if you're not inheriting from a class or including a module it's impossible to reason about the Runnable class. Where are `answer?` and `message` defined? How do you test it?